# Is it possible to have a python shell in a py2exe build?

Tags: python, py2exe, distutils

I distribute a software package for windows via distutils and py2exe.  For development purposes, I'd like to be able to have access to a python console inside the py2exe build.  I see there is a `python27.dll` file in the py2exe build, so I hope I can leverage that to launch a python terminal.

Is it possible to take an existing, or modify distutils/py2exe to get end user access to a Python shell in the py2exe environment?

Comment: yes ... look into pycrust

Comment: pycrust depends on wxWindows, which can be a non-starter if you're not already using it. wxWindows has some problems on recent OSX as well. YMMV!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a really bare-bones way to accomplish this as documented by Matt Anderson from the pymntos google group. I've seen some variations on it, but this one came up first when I googled. :p

The juice is in the stdlib [code](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html) module, leveraging code.InteractiveInterpeter. The only thing you'd have to do is add this in as a thread as the application starts. Then, when the app starts you can telnet 'localhost 7777' and you should drop into a Python interpreter.

The problem with doing it as a thread though - you can't very easily twiddle variables / data in the main thread without doing some sort of queue and passing things around.

You could alternatively have an async socket - that way you could twiddle stuff as a main-thread participant. Thats inherently dangerous for a host of reasons. But, we're talking bare metal.

If you use the Twisted library, you could use [Twisted Conch](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedConch), which allows you to create an SSH or Telnet server  that can talk to the rest of your app. However, this might be a problem since you're using the event loop from the UI to process events - you can't have two event loops. If you're using Qt, there is a Twisted Qt Reactor event loop. If it's windows or something else.. I have no idea. But, this should at least give you a few things to consider.

Original link is: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pymntos/-Mjviu7R2bs

```
import socket
import code
import sys

class MyConsole(code.InteractiveConsole):
    def __init__(self, rfile, wfile, locals=None):
        self.rfile = rfile
        self.wfile = wfile
        code.InteractiveConsole.__init__(
            self, locals=locals, filename='<MyConsole>')

    def raw_input(self, prompt=''):
        self.wfile.write(prompt)
        return self.rfile.readline().rstrip()

    def write(self, data):
        self.wfile.write(data)


netloc = ('', 7777)
servsock = socket.socket()
servsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
servsock.bind(netloc)
servsock.listen(5)
print 'listening'
sock, _ = servsock.accept()
print 'accepted'

rfile = sock.makefile('r', 0)
sys.stdout = wfile = sock.makefile('w', 0)

console = MyConsole(rfile, wfile)
console.interact()
```